# Method didn't throw UnsupportedOperationException, eventhough it should

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging

For some reason I have been able execute an removeAll on an extension of AbstractList.

In particular that list was an java.util.Arrays.Arraylist (which is not java.util.ArrayList), which is an extension of AbstractList that doesn't support remove or add.

After changing the following lines

```
    Set<String> defaultList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(getDefaultNames()));
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(_adapter.getContainerNames());

    defaultList.removeAll(names);
```

To

```
    List<String> defaultList = Arrays.asList(getDefaultNames());
    List<String> names = _adapter.getContainerNames();

    defaultList.removeAll(names);
```

I was able to compile the code, execute it and see the list in sorted order, even after deinstalling the app completely.

After coming back from eating, **removing all the breakpoints (I had a breakpoint in every line)**, and switching between the old and new version a few times (checking out each version in git, compiling and installing), instead of having a sorted list, I got an UnsupportedOperationException.

Now I found out from the implementation visible in the android.jar.java.util.Arrays open source code that this should have never executed.

I'm seriously baffled and I'm guessing this is some kind caching bug or due to maybe not building clean, but how could something like this occur ?

Is this to be expected and potentially reproducable ?

How can I avoid this in the future? Do I have to do build clean everytime ?

Did the breakpoints somehow prevent this code from correctly building clean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possible explanations, and you have already mentioned some. To me it appears that the most likely explanation is that in your case `removeAll()` only throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` if you actually try to remove one or more elements through it.

I just tried this:

```
Arrays.asList("Ole", "No").removeAll(Collections.singletonList("HopefullyHelpful"));
```

It runs fine on my computer, no sign of any exception. I am using Java 8, so it *may* not run fine on Android, but you can try. I didn’t find anything in the documentation that would allow this, though.

While remains from a previous build is another possible explanation, your breakpoints certainly ought not have anything to do with your observations.